# How to handle wp_query?

Tags: wp-query

I want one particular category insert 12 post, but I only see some few posts.

Just like first time first 4 post and other time other post. What can I do?

<sup>***Editor note:***

I understand the issue is showing 4 posts in the first query, and the rest (8 from 12 in total) in the second query.</sup>

This is the code for the first time query:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query('cat=6&order=ASC&showposts=4'); ?>
<?php  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="padding-10">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="latestpost-dis">
            <div class="date"> <?php the_date(); ?> <span>BY</span> <?php the_author(); ?></div>
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <p class="margin-top-20"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
```

And this for the second time query:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query('cat=6&order=ASC&showposts=-1,-2,-3,-4');?>
<?php  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="padding-10">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="latestpost-dis">
            <div class="date"> <?php the_date(); ?> <span>BY</span> <?php the_author(); ?></div>
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <p class="margin-top-20"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: could you please reword your question correcting the grammar & explaining the problem you're having?

Comment: have you read: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Please don't use bold for whole sentences. And please keep in mind that this is a Q/A site and not a forum, so proper Upper-/lowercase letters are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You're not showing your entire code, so not all of these suggestions may be relevant:

1. Use distinct, ideally descriptive, names for the variables that hold the different queries. Using the same variable, `$my_query`, can lead to unintended consequences.
2. Be sure to close the first loop properly, with `endwhile; endif;`, before opening the second loop.
3. Be sure to call `wp_reset_postdata();` between the loops.
4. If your intent is merely to *offset* the second loop by the posts returned in the first loop, use [the **`offset`** parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Offset_Parameter), rather than explicitly excluding post IDs.
5. As @eric-holmes indicated, `showposts` is the wrong (and a deprecated) parameter to use, and should be replaced with `posts_per_page`.

Example:

```
$query4posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'cat' => 6,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 4
) );

$query8posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'cat' => 6,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'offset' => 4
) ); 

// Output first loop of 4 posts
if ( $query4posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $query4posts->have_posts() ) : $query4posts->the_post();
    // Loop output
endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

// Output second loop of 8 posts, offset
if ( $query8posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $query8posts->have_posts() ) : $query8posts->the_post();
    // Loop output
endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: To make it more efficient, you should query all 12 posts at once & then check the value of `$query->current_post` to come out of the first loop

Comment: Oh, there are surely more efficient approaches; this just answers the OP's question as-written, with respect to making two separate custom queries play nicely together.

Answer (score 2):

Your Query code is perfect. The problem is your arguments. [`showposts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) is deprecated, you should be using [`posts_per_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) instead. It defines HOW MANY posts show up - hence why you are getting 4 posts in your first example. Your second example makes no sense, so that is probably why you are getting strange output.

Answer (score 1):

First I would not use `showposts=` anymore as it will eventually be eliminated.

Have you tried using `$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' );` instead?

Also double check how many posts you have set to display via your admin settings.